# in c#, how to determine the object's type when List<Object> is given?

Tags: c#, list, types, covariance, contravariance

my method look something like:

```
Boolean actions(List<Object> input)
{
    if (input.element is String)
    {...}
    else if (input.element is PSObject)
    {...}
}
```

I tried `input.getType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == new PSObject().GetType())`

but `input.getType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` says it is object type...

Comment: So what's wrong with the current code and `is`? The generic type, `X`, in `List<X>` is `Object` in this case - that is, the static type known at compilation.

Comment: -1 (Can be corrected) Specify the applicable error messages/indicators.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps your problem is just that you are trying to use `input.element` to get an item out of the list. That's not the correct way to check the type of an element in the list.

Just use this to test the first item only:

```
bool actions(List<Object> input)
{
    var element = input.FirstOrDefault();
    if (element is String)
    {...}
    else if (element is PSObject)
    {...}
}
```

Or this to test each item individually:

```
bool actions(List<Object> input)
{
    foreach (var element in input)
    {
        if (element is String)
        {...}
        else if (element is PSObject)
        {...}
    }
}
```

Or if you want to ensure that all elements of a list are of a given type, you can use generics:

```
bool actions<T>(List<T> input)
{
    if (typeof(String).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
    {...}
    else if (typeof(PSObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
    {...}
}
```

Comment: +1 Good eyes .. and this is why posts should always include the correct/applicable error messages.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel No, the issue is that List<X> is String is *never* true, but the first element might be a String ..

Comment: @FlyingStreudel - Any value types will already be boxed in a `List<object>`.

Comment: But just because the first item is a string doesn't mean the second can't be a `PSObect`, so this would need to be very carefully used.  If that's a constraint you wanted then the method should be generic.

Comment: @Servy true, but without further context, it's hard to give a more complete answer.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yeah.  The big thing for me is that if they should all be of the same type you'd want to use generics.  If they don't, then accepting a `List<object>` and checking the type for each item is what you need to do (unless you can use an interface).

Comment: @Servy included generic alternative

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the type of the instances in the list, not the type of the list.

```
Boolean actions(List<Object> input) {
  foreach (object o in input) {
    if (o is String) {
      ...
    } else if (o is PSObject) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you know that all the objects in the list are of the same type, you could check the type of the first item (`input[0]`) and then do the same thing to all items depending on that.

Answer (score 2):

> but input.getType().GetGenericArguments()[0] says it is object type...

Well, as `List<T>` is invariant, the generic argument of the list passed in will **always** match the generic argument of the method parameter, exactly.

In this case, the list will **always** be a list of `object`s.

Now, each item in the list may not be an `object` (as it's most derived type), it could be a string, or a `PSObject`.  However you can't assume that *all* of them are any type other than `object`.

So you could check if there is a more derived type for a particular item in the list, but not of the list as a whole.

So it's more likely that you'll have to refactor the code to do:

```
Boolean actions(List<Object> input)
{
    foreach(object element in input)
    {
        if (element is String)
        {...}
        else if (element is PSObject)
        {...}
    }
}
```

If it's important for all of the items to be of the same type then you can use generics:

```
Boolean actions<T>(List<T> input)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {...}
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(PSObject))
    {...}
}
```

Comment: As you stated that `List<T>` is invariant, isn't `typeof(T)` **always** `typeof(object)` if input was `List<object>`?

Comment: @KenKin Yes, but since the method is generic you are no longer required to pass in a `List<object>`, you can and should be passing in a list of a more derived type, that's the idea of that particular implementation.